# Application testing (Multiple IP's)

Tags: java, networking, udp, ip, p2p

I've been developing a P2P application that i have to test now. The problem is, that i cant figure out how to test the multiple instances of the application on one computer. 
The application is made in Java and I'm running it on OSX. I'm of course getting an error about the address being used.

The test only has to show that packets are transmitted between the different peers in the network.

Answer (score 6):

You should use different port numbers for different peers.

Comment: +1, I think this is the right answer. Assuming several instances can run on the one machine without interfering with each other, I imagine simply using different port numbers would do the trick. Does this run from the CLI, or inside an application server? OP, can you clarify?

Comment: Server has to listen for incoming connections and as soon as one comes, we create a socket for the new peer. Upon creation of that socket we ought to create a new thread that waits for incoming packages from that particular peer. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that by CLI you meant client. If you mean CLI(command line interface) then I have to say I used only my Eclipse IDE. I think you could test a simple app with several telnets too.

Comment: Yes, CLI = command line interface. If you launch from Eclipse, that's fine, but I should imagine that just runs the Java run-time environment in a new telnet session. If you can start instances on (for example) localhost:10000, localhost:10001, localhost:10002, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If it's P2P then the best testing is of course on multiple machines.  You could setup a virtual environment on your machine and test it using a couple VM's.  I'm not sure how to do this on OSX but I would think you could.

Comment: He should be able to setup a virtual machine using VirtualBox.  Since he is running OS X he can create a OS X guest machine without a problem,

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to exchange data between two peers located in the same pc, then using different ports should be sufficient. But if your peer supports many ip addresses, you can try to assign them a different one too.

Keep in mind that firewalls installed on PC can sometime silently kill packets (I've see that under Windows), especially if you use multicasting or loop back addresses.

Last, if you test your application successfully on a PC, it may not work well when deployed on multiple peers, because the network plumbing is complex and tricky. A system where peers share the same IP address usually does not behave like a system where peers each have their own IP addresses.

Answer (score -1):

> The problem is, that i cant figure out how to test the multiple
>   instances of the application on one computer.

You should be able to start up two instances of the application and configure them differently.  If you are unable to do this, then connect two computers together, and test it that way.

> The test only has to show that packets are transmitted between the
>   different peers in the network.

You are going to verify the CORRECT packets are being sent, right?

Comment: I'll just try to configure them differently. And yes, I'm indeed going to verify that the correct packets are being sent.